# Set names for header columns - expected 14 column names

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple user form that collects informations about persons.

Here an example of what I get when I added informations of 6 persons. I want to start the list of informations from the 3th row (since the 2 first ones are filled by Command button "Remplir formulaire" :

[image: Example of filled form]

My issue is that I would like, at the calling of userForm, to have 14 headers names for each first 14 columns (the functions to fill the values into these columns will be done later in my code).

To set the names of the 14 fields (starting from row=3), I did :

```
Private Sub ResetForm()

'Monsieur by default
ComboBox1.Value = "Monsieur"

'Empty TextBox1
TextBox1.Value = ""

'Empty TextBox2
TextBox2.Value = ""

'Empty TextBox3
TextBox3.Value = ""

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

'Create header for each colum
Dim HeaderName(14) As String

'Index to browse HeaderName array
Dim a As Integer

HeaderName(1) = "Civilité"
HeaderName(2) = "Nom"
HeaderName(3) = "Prénom"
HeaderName(4) = "Âge"
HeaderName(5) = "Fonction"
HeaderName(6) = "Entité"
HeaderName(7) = "Catégorie"
HeaderName(8) = "Adresse"
HeaderName(9) = "Code postal"
HeaderName(10) = "Ville"
HeaderName(11) = "Tél Fixe"
HeaderName(12) = "Tél Portable"
HeaderName(13) = "Email"
HeaderName(14) = "Autres infos"

'Initlialize headers : start from row = 3
Sheet1.Activate
With Sheet1
      For a = 1 To 14
           If (.Cells(3, a) <> "") Then
             .Cells(3, a).Value = HeaderName(a)
           End If
           Debug.Print "a = " & a
      Next a
End With

'Fill ComboBox
With ComboBox1
    .AddItem "Monsieur"
    .AddItem "Madame"
End With

'Set Elu by default
CheckBox1.Value = True
CheckBox2.Value = False

'Reset all inputs
Call ResetForm

End Sub
```

and into the same VBA source, I did for Command button" "Remplir Formulaire" :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim emptyRow As Long

Sheet1.Activate

With Sheet1
emptyRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count + .UsedRange.Rows(1).Row - 1
    If .Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value <> "" Then
        emptyRow = emptyRow + 1
        .Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = ComboBox1.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = TextBox1.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = TextBox2.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = TextBox3.Value
        .Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = CheckBox1.Value

        If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
           .Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = CheckBox1.Caption
        Else
           .Cells(emptyRow, 5).Value = CheckBox2.Caption
        End If
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

So I don't understand why I can't get the 14 names of each top column specified in function `UserForm_Initialize()` by `HeaderName` array; only the first four ones (Civilité, Nom, Prénom, Age) are displayed when I click on "Remplir Formulaire" command button, not the 10 others.

What might be wrong here?

Comment: Don't you mean `If (.Cells(3, a) = "") Then`?

Comment: -@BigBen thanks, stupid error, I did confusions with different and equal operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you really need to check if the cell is empty?  I would replace the 20+ lines of code with:

```
Sheet1.Range("A3").Resize(1, 14).Value = Array("Civilité", "Nom", "Prénom", "Âge", "Fonction", "Entité", "Catégorie", "Adresse", "Code postal", "Ville", "Tél Fixe", "Tél Portable", "Email", "Autres infos")
```